# Implementing TLV in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, hex, tlv

I am trying to implement TLV for e-invoice in Javascript. I am able to convert the values to hex and from hex to base64. When I add the base64 value to the QRcode and try to test it, I get an error telling me there is something wrong with my data. Below is my implementation

```
const  __toString = (tag, value) => {
    const tagToHex = "0"+(tag).toString(16)
    const valueLengthToHex = value.length <= 15 ? "0" + (value.length).toString(16) :(value.length).toString(16)
    const valueToHex = this.toHex(value)

    return `${tagToHex}${valueLengthToHex}${valueToHex}`;
}

const toHex = (str) => {
    let result = '';
    for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
      result += str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    return result;
}
```

`Entry point`

```
const generateString = [
    __toString(1, 'Bobs Records'),
    __toString(2, '310122393500003'),
    __toString(3, '2022-04-25T15:30:00Z'),
    __toString(4, '1000.00'),
    __toString(5, '150.00'),
];

return btoa(generateString.join(''))
```

`MDEwYzQyNmY2MjczMjA1MjY1NjM2ZjcyNjQ3MzAyMGYzMzMxMzAzMTMyMzIzMzM5MzMzNTMwMzAzMDMwMzMwMzE0MzIzMDMyMzIyZDMwMzQyZDMyMzU1NDMxMzUzYTMzMzAzYTMwMzA1YTA0MDczMTMwMzAzMDJlMzAzMDA1MDYzMTM1MzAyZTMwMzA=`

I get the base64 string above. When I set it as the value of the qrcode and try to scan it, I get errors and I do not know where I am missing it.

Comment: What are these mysterious errors that you get? Do you have an example of known working QR code to compare what's wrong with your version?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I no longer have an example

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use this NPM package `npm i --save @axenda/zatca` to solve the problem. For more info, visit this page https://github.com/axenda/zatca